# Ηtaccess fail to point index.php on subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, https, no-www

I'm trying to set an htaccess file to remove `.php` and `.html` extension, force `non-www` and `https` but it's failing on `index.php` inside subdirectories.

I have the following syntax in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 

# Redirect www and http to https - non-www
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Start php extension remove
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
# End php extension remove    

# Start html extension remove
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
# End html extension remove
```

It works perfectly on `https` and `non-www` but when I point the en subdirectory (`domain.com/en`) I get the following message on the browser:

> The requested URL /en.php was not found on this server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Path to subdirectory would be domain.com/en/ (ended with slash).

domain.com/en is not a directory/file so RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php is true and requested /en.php

Comment: Would you suggest another strategy on htaccess?